# Setting the date in a object to yesterdays date

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a need to be able to set a param in an object to yesterday date like the following:

But i am stumped as to how bets to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>board</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sitetdl.com/javascripts/api/v.js"></script> 
<object class="Viz" width="1060" height="860" style="display:none;" /> 
  <param name="customViews" value="no" />
  <param name="site_root" value="" /> 
  <param name="host_url" value="https://sitetdl.com/" />
  <param name="name" value="DashDemo/SALES" />
  <param name="filter" value="DateSelected=2014-01-28 00:00"/> 
  <param name="tabs" value="no" /> 
  <param name="toolbar" value="top" /> 
</object> 
<form> 
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only Javascript:

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("Viz");
// Make sure we find the Viz object
if(obj.length) {
    // Iterate over the list of <param> child nodes
    var children = obj[0].children;
    var len = children.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        // If we find the filter tag...
        if(children[i].name == "filter") {
            var yesterday = new Date();
            yesterday.setDate(new Date().getDate()-1);
            children[i].value = "DateSelected="+yesterday.getFullYear()+"-"+formatNumber(yesterday.getMonth()+1)+"-"+formatNumber(yesterday.getDate());
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Helper function for formatting the date
function formatNumber(number) {
    return number < 10 ? "0" + number : number;
}
```

If you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) it's even easier:

```
document.querySelector(".Viz param[name='filter']").value = 
    "DateSelected="+yesterday.getFullYear()+"-"+formatNumber(yesterday.getMonth()+1)+"-"+formatNumber(yesterday.getDate());
```

And finally, you have an issue with your syntax:

```
<object class="Viz" width="1060" height="860" style="display:none;" />
                                                                   ^^
```

Don't close off the object tag here, as this invalidates the subsequent HTML.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUwRV/1/) of the above. I didn't add the time in as I wasn't sure if you just wanted a hardcoded `00:00` or the current time, but you can easily figure this out from the code above.

Comment: The javascript one worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
var yesterday = function () { var date = new Date(); date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1); return date; }
```

Then just use the function to get yesterdays date:

```
var date = yesterday();
```